# Determine or access the concrete type of a type variable at runtime

Tags: scala, reflection, type-variables

Given the following:

```
trait A

trait Service{
  type tA <: A
  def ping(a:tA)    
}

// implementations
class A1 extends A
class A2 extends A

class ServiceA1{
  type tA = A1
  def ping(a:tA){println("Service for A1")}
}

class ServiceA2{
  type tA = A2
  def ping(a:tA){println("Service for A2")}
}

// a collection of services
val services = Seq(new ServiceA1, new ServiceA2, ....)

// find the service that supports A1
services.find(_.tA =:= A1)
```

Obviously the above won't compile. Is there any way to determine at runtime the concrete type of the type variable?

Comment: Type-erasure makes this impossible in the general case, but in the example you've given its `A1` if the value is a `ServiceA1`, i.e. `services.find(_.isInstanceOf[Service1])` would work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a abstract method (`tATag`) to your `Service` trait that returns the TypeTag of `tA`, implement this in `ServiceA1` and `ServiceA2` (btw your services should extend the `Service` trait) accordingly and use this when comparing, like this:

```
trait Service {
  type tA <: A
  def ping(a:tA)
  def tATag: TypeTag[tA]
}

class ServiceA1 extends Service {
  type tA = A1
  def ping(a:tA){println("Service for A1")}
  def tATag = typeTag[A1]
}

class ServiceA2 extends Service {
  type tA = A2
  def ping(a:tA){println("Service for A2")}
  def tATag = typeTag[A2]
}

// a collection of services
val services = Seq(new ServiceA1, new ServiceA2)

// find the service that supports A1
services.find(s => s.tATag.tpe =:= typeOf[A1])
```